# Installing PHP5.3 on Windows Vista x64 with IIS7

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, installation, php, iis

I have successfully installed PHP5.3 but cannot seem to get it to work on IIS7.  I have followed the tutorial on iis.net (http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-70/) and can clearly see in the IIS Console that the mapping for *.php files should execute php-cgi.exe as a Fast CGI module.  However, when I try to load a php page in my browser, I see no output.  Any suggestions on how to debug this?

Comment: Running IIS7, Windows Vista Home Premium x64, PHP5.3 NTS x86 via FastCGI ... I now realize I probably need the x64 version of PHP5.3, but cannot seem to find a build for it on the php download site.

Comment: Found some x64 version downloads at http://windows.php.net/download/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [forum post](http://forums.iis.net/p/1147812/1863035.aspx#1863035) over at iis.net where wendac give instructions on how he got your same situation to work: Vista x64, IIS 7 and PHP 5.

I would think that the most important step that you might be missing is step 6:

> 6)  Right click on the Application Pool that you want to run PHP on and select
>   “Advanced Settings…” or select the
>   same from the Actions pane after
>   selecting the Application pool
>
> Change the “Enable 32-bit Applications” to
>   True (if you want the application pool
>   to spawn in a 32-bit mode)
>
> Click OK

Comment: While that did not initially work, I uninstalled PHP and removed the IIS settings completely.  Then enabled 32-bit applications and installed PHP 5.3 x86 and let it configure IIS to run it as a FastCGI module and it worked perfectly!  Thanks for the tip.